# How to Write Custom Directive for DecimalPipe in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have created currency directive like

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MyCurrencyPipe } from "./my-currency.pipe";

@Directive({ selector: "[myCurrencyFormatter]" })
export class MyCurrencyFormatterDirective implements OnInit {

    private el: any;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private currencyPipe: MyCurrencyPipe
    ) {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value);
    }

    @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
    onFocus(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.parse(value); // opossite of transform
    }

    @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
    onBlur(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }

}
```

I followed this link http://plnkr.co/edit/rKq8yCoNhwXFozKsKPZf?p=preview

But how to create DecimalPipe Dynamically

example decimal pipe

```
@Component({
  selector: 'number-pipe',
  template: `<div>  

    <p> {{pi | number:'1.2-2'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class NumberPipeComponent {
  pi: number = 3;
}
```

if I give 3 in text box then I want to get 3.00 on ng-model change event.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'how to create DecimalPipe Dynamically'?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: can you provide some more examples of the desired output?